# Source of Thunderbird's Default Theme by Arvid Axelsson

Tags: themes, xul, thunderbird

I need to edit the original icons from Thunderbird's Default Theme by Arvid Axelsson.
Does Mozilla provides an SVG version?

I need to know the style of the icons, because they're really specific (inner-shadow etc). It's not a simple `-moz-effect` (CSS). Does anybody know where to find or download the real skin-source or how to view files inside `chrome://global/skin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually three default themes - Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. You seem to be talking about the Windows theme which is indeed being attributed to Arvid Axelsson even though he doesn't seem to be working on it (looks like he created the theme around Thunderbird 1.0 and other people took over since).

Looking at the [source code repository](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/themes/qute/mail/), the icons are there but their source code isn't. I also checked the bugs associated with icon changes and the source code of these icons indeed doesn't seem to be public. Which means that the only way for you would be contacting the person who designed the icons. That would be Andreas Nilsson, click his name in [bug 671236](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671236) to send him a mail.

Comment: Mozillazine Discussion: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=2298101